# RedundantArgumentMatcherException in azure pipeline when field is used and not when using local variable

Tags: c#, unit-testing, nhibernate, azure-pipelines, xunit

I have an issue that only occurs in my Azure pipeline when running unit tests. The unit tests fail when the methods in the test use the field `rankGenerator`instead of a local variable of the same field. The class examples are written below.

This first code block has rankGenerator as a field, and the pipeline fails with the error message: `NSubstitute.Exceptions.RedundantArgumentMatcherException : Some argument specifications (e.g. Arg.Is, Arg.Any) were left over after the last call.`

However, if `rankGenerator` is first declared as a local variable, then the pipeline doesn't fail. Does anyone have an explanation for this behavior?

**Failing test example:**

```cs
public class RiskTests
{
    private readonly IRankGenerator rankGenerator = Substitute.For<IRankGenerator>();
    private const string OriginalRisk = "Danger danger";
    private const string OriginalRank = "Rank 1";
    private Risk sut;

    public RiskTests()
    {
        sut = Risk.Create(CreateTestActivity(), OriginalRisk, OriginalRank);
        rankGenerator(
            Arg.Is<string>(x => x == null || !string.IsNullOrEmpty(x)), 
            Arg.Is<string>(x => x == null || !string.IsNullOrEmpty(x)))
           .GenerateRank().ReturnsForAnyArgs(_ => "000001");
    }

    [Fact]
    public void Should_Add_Mitigation()
    {
        sut.AddMitigation("Do this to be safe", rankGenerator);
        
        sut.Mitigations.ShouldNotBeEmpty();
        sut.Mitigations.Count.ShouldBe(1);
        
        sut.AddMitigation("And this is important", rankGenerator);
        sut.Mitigations.Count.ShouldBe(2);
    }
}
```

**Passed test example:**

```cs
public class RiskTests
{
    private readonly IRankGenerator rankGenerator = Substitute.For<IRankGenerator>();
    private const string OriginalRisk = "Danger danger";
    private const string OriginalRank = "Rank 1";
    private Risk sut;

    public RiskTests()
    {
        sut = Risk.Create(CreateTestActivity(), OriginalRisk, OriginalRank);
        rankGenerator(
            Arg.Is<string>(x => x == null || !string.IsNullOrEmpty(x)), 
            Arg.Is<string>(x => x == null || !string.IsNullOrEmpty(x)))
           .GenerateRank().ReturnsForAnyArgs(_ => "000001");
    }

    [Fact]
    public void Should_Add_Mitigation()
    {
        var localRankGenerator = rankGenerator;
        sut.AddMitigation("Do this to be safe", localRankGenerator);
        
        sut.Mitigations.ShouldNotBeEmpty();
        sut.Mitigations.Count.ShouldBe(1);
        
        sut.AddMitigation("And this is important", localRankGenerator);
        sut.Mitigations.Count.ShouldBe(2);
    }
}
```

**Pipeline definition**

```yaml
   - task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
     inputs:
       command: 'test'
       projects: '**/RigPlan.sln'
       arguments: '--filter CI!=false'
       testRunTitle: 'Run .Net Tests'
```

Comment: I forgot to mention that the azure pipeline is running on windows, so the fault could be that the pipeline doesn't run the tests in parallel.

Comment: May i know if you tried the Failing test sample on local machine? Does it succeed or have same error with pipeline? What come to my mind is the variable scope. when you declare it as a local variable within a specific test method, its scope is limited to that method. When rankGenerator is a field, it has a global scope within the class. This means it persists across multiple test methods.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I forgot to mention that none of the unit test samples fail on a local machine.

Comment: Thanks @Steffen. It's recommended to share the pipeline definition if it only fails on DevOps pipeline.

Comment: @wadezhou-MSFT I'm not sure on how much of the pipeline i'm allowed to share, however i added the task that fails. Not sure if this helps you alot.

Comment: Cannot find issue from the task code. May i know it's an error or just a message for `NSubstitute.Exceptions.RedundantArgumentMatcherException ....`? Is this [link](https://github.com/nsubstitute/NSubstitute/issues/565) helpful?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean but the pipeline says the unit tests fails and the error message is: `NSubstitute.Exceptions.RedundantArgumentMatcherException ....`